Problema al usar Emit con JS para livewire
He creado un nuevo proyecto de Laravel para probar Emit de Livewire para poder actualizar el contendido del componente con un valor que este fuera de este. Sin embargo, al hacer clic en el botón para emitir un evento, me aparece el siguiente error en la consola del navegador:
Uncaught TypeError: Livewire.emit is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.
este es mi HTMl que use:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Livewire Input Update</title>
    @livewireStyles
</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" id="inputExterno" placeholder="Escribe algo...">
    <button id="botonActualizar">Actualizar Input del Componente</button>

    @livewire('input-component')

    @livewireScripts
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            const inputExterno = document.getElementById('inputExterno');
            const boton = document.getElementById('botonActualizar');

            boton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                const valor = inputExterno.value;
                console.log('Valor emitido: ', valor);
                Livewire.emit('actualizarValor', valor);
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>


Este es la logica del componente:
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class InputComponent extends Component
{
    public $valorInput = '';

    protected $listeners = ['actualizarValor'];

    public function actualizarValor($valor)
    {
        $this->valorInput = $valor;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.input-component');
    }
}


Y este es la vista del componente
<div>
    <input type="text" wire:model="valorInput" placeholder="Este se actualizará">
</div>


